# How to enhance SilverStripe FullTextSearchable search results?

Tags: php, search, silverstripe

I have enabled SilverStripe's `FulltextSearchable` in my `_config.php` file. I want to enhance the results of FulltextSearchable's default search.

The default search results are as follows:

- If I search a single word that exists, it shows a result. OK
- If I change only a letter from this word, it does not find anything. BAD
- If I search multiple words, it does not find anything, except if these words are exactly like in the database. BAD

I don't want to use a Google custom Search module in my site.

Is there an easy way to enhance `FullTextSearchable` to find multiple words and to return better results?

Comment: Thanks @3dgoo for a better english

Comment: I had good results using https://github.com/g4b0/silverstripe-searchable-dataobjects module instead of standard search. Biggest pro: you can define for each page type / dataobject what content can be searched.

Comment: Yes I tried it. But I need a better search algorithm. Like partial, incomplete, look like search engine instead of a standard search with %$query%. I am using actually (DataObject::get("Page","MATCH (Title,Content) AGAINST ('%$query%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"); ) Results are bad.

Comment: Well, "better algorithm" also means: another search module / engine. You could try out elastic, solr etc... which also means: a bit to set up first. There is an elastic module out there which looks nice. http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/weboftalent/elastica

Comment: Hi @Wmk yeah It look like what I am look for. Little complicated to setup at the beggining for realizable. Unfortunatly, on docs of elastica, it failed on silverstripe 3.2 and more. I will take a look for solr. Thanks

Comment: @wmk I've found a ElasticaSearch service on Amazon : https://aws.amazon.com/en/elasticsearch-service/ Is that configurable with the addon you recommand? Thanks!

Comment: I've found another thing on google, a tutorial : https://3sq.re/blog/2014/11/integrating-searchly-elasticsearch-silverstripe/ But in the last step I dont under how run this from my site hosting. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Fulltextsearch module (Different from `FullTextSearchable`): https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-fulltextsearch. It uses Solr, and allows many different and flexible ways to index and subsequently search your `SiteTree` and `DataObject` subclasses using the Lucene search-syntax (Which is abstracted away from you).

Warning: While the module is stable, and flexible, with this comes the potential for complexity. Read the docs (well!) and don't be afraid to ask more questions on silverstripe.org or SO :-)

Comment: I've been long to answer. I found that solution is good enough